# R markdown KableExtra latex table booktabs not working

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kableextra

I want to create a latex table in R markdown using KableExtra package, with `format = "latex"`. According to the description, I only need to add `booktabs = T` in kable like:

```
kable(ds1, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped"))
```

However I generate this error:

> Quitting from lines 33-179 (PJ1_Rcode.Rmd)  Error in
>   header_rows_start:header_rows_end : NA/NaN argument Calls: 
>   ... kable_styling -> pdfTable_styling -> styling_latex_striped In
>   addition: Warning message: package 'kableExtra' was built under R
>   version 3.4.4  Execution halted

I've already add:

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{longtable}
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{multirow}
  - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  - \usepackage{wrapfig}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{colortbl}
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
  - \usepackage{tabu}
  - \usepackage{threeparttable}
  - \usepackage{threeparttablex}
  - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
  - \usepackage{makecell}
```

in the yaml part.

Comment: Is `ds1` a matrix without column names? If you give it column names or convert it to a dataframe, I think this should work OK.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed ds1 to datafram and give it column names, now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make sure that your R and RStudio versions are up to date as this is a major issue faced.
kindly also through some light on the kind of object/data you are passing as 'ds1'

Comment: Although the version isn't the major problem here, it still causes a lot of warnings. Guess I need to update it constantly. Thanks!